# Sinister particles rendering experience, Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: modeling, rendering, particles, artifacts

I don't know for sure if this happens too with blender 2.80 (My last experience), but I'm facing bad rendering problems on my laptop with my on-board card, Blender 2.92 - Intel HD Graphics. And that starts when I add hair particles on Suzanne (3D Mesh). It's really impossible to do anything:

[image: Bad rendering]

As anyone can see, I simply added hair particle to object and didn't change anything. I don't think it's normal to add hair particle and get that in the end. There's probably not much I can do on this conditions.

It was supposed to look like this:

[image: Inspiration work]

But I get in return this:
[image: Bad Rendering]

I know some Integrated cards are slower and offers less shader cores, but it fairs decently on some HD games. I face slower rendering speed with simple objects too. It's not I want to make high poly or very complex objects as game assets, but a remarkable quality is very desirable.

[image]

Comment: If you tried it with a new file and default Monkey ... Hair lenght doesnt correspond to 4m. Attach your blend via https://blend-exchange.com given code copy-paste into your Q.

Comment: That's true. And Blender is slow on simple rendering operations too. And it's not because of full system resources usage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some ideas of what it could be. First off, What is the scale of your object? 4-meter hair seems long for an unscaled Suzanne. I'd try lowering that value first.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! It's being really difficult to handle previous releases tutorials on newer Blender version.

Comment: Suzanne scale: X = 0.258, Y = 0.260, Z = 0.345